# Xcode CodeSigning fails on self-hosted action runner with error 'Warning: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer...'

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

I'm currently using a macos GitHub runner from their virtual environments for CI/CD for my iOS application. This works very well.

To sign the app, the Apple certificate and provisioning profile is set on the GitHub runner with the credentials stored in GitHub secrets in a step in the workflow file:

```
    - name: Install the Apple certificate and provisioning profile
  env:
    BUILD_CERTIFICATE_BASE64: ${{ secrets.IOS_ENTERPRISE_CERTIFICATE_BASE64 }}
    P12_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.IOS_ENTERPRISE_CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD }}
    BUILD_PROVISION_PROFILE_BASE64: ${{ secrets.IOS__PROVISION_PROFILE_BASE64 }}
    KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.IOS_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD }}
  run: |
    # create variables
    CERTIFICATE_PATH=$RUNNER_TEMP/build_certificate.p12
    PP_PATH=$RUNNER_TEMP/build_pp.mobileprovision
    KEYCHAIN_PATH=$RUNNER_TEMP/app-signing.keychain-db

    # import certificate and provisioning profile from secrets
    echo -n "$BUILD_CERTIFICATE_BASE64" | base64 --decode -o $CERTIFICATE_PATH
    echo -n "$BUILD_PROVISION_PROFILE_BASE64" | base64 --decode -o $PP_PATH

    # create temporary keychain
    security create-keychain -p "$KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD" $KEYCHAIN_PATH
    security set-keychain-settings -lut 21600 $KEYCHAIN_PATH
    security unlock-keychain -p "$KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD" $KEYCHAIN_PATH

    # import certificate to keychain
    security import $CERTIFICATE_PATH -P "$P12_PASSWORD" -A -t cert -f pkcs12 -k $KEYCHAIN_PATH
    security list-keychain -d user -s $KEYCHAIN_PATH

    # apply provisioning profile
    mkdir -p ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles
    cp $PP_PATH ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles
```

This code is exactly copied from the GitHub documentation from here:

https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.5/actions/deployment/deploying-xcode-applications/installing-an-apple-certificate-on-macos-runners-for-xcode-development

They iOS build itself is done with the lane `build_ios_app` with fastlane.

Because the GitHub runners are very expensive, I want to switch to a self-hosted runner with a MacMini M1.

**But here is the problem:**

The MacMini is set up with a admin user called `runner` and installed the action-runner script according to documentation from GitHub.

The MacMini was completely new installed with no certificate or profiles in the keychain.

But the build always fails with the following error:

```
** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CodeSign /Users/runner/actions-runner/_work/{someFolder}/{someFolder}/iosApp/Build/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/iosApp/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/iosApp.app (in target 'iosApp' from project 'iosApp')
(1 failure)
[12:31:13]: Exit status: 65

+---------------+------------------------------+
|              Build environment               |
+---------------+------------------------------+
| xcode_path    | /Applications/Xcode_14.2.app |
| gym_version   | 2.212.1                      |
| export_method | enterprise                   |
| sdk           | iPhoneOS16.2.sdk             |
+---------------+------------------------------+

[12:31:13]: ▸ Warning: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer "iPhone Distribution: {MyName}"
[12:31:13]: ▸ /Users/runner/actions-runner/_work/{someFolder}/{someFolder}/iosApp/Build/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/iosApp/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/iosApp.app: errSecInternalComponent
[12:31:13]: ▸ Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I don't get why it's running perfectly on GitHub runner environment, but NOT in my self-hosted runner environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution (which worked for me)**

The issue was, that the MacMini machine was missing the `Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority` certificate in the keychain.

Actually this will automatically be installed by Xcode, but for some reason this was not the case on my machine.

Important is, that the certificate will be imported to the system keychain.

The certificate can be downloaded here:

https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/

To find the correct certificate matching your iOS Distribution certificate you have to check the information of your iOS Distribution certificate:

[image]

For me it was the Authority G3. Download and import the correct one from the Apple PKI (link above) to your system keychain:

[image]

Now all my failed runs with `CodeSign` was gone.

Answer (score 1):

I'll provide a few more details regarding why this issue happens. When running the runner as a service, login keychain is not accessible to the CodeSign tool (and I think in general as well).

Since "Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority" was installed by default in the login keychain, CodeSign tool failed.

I think this is the reason downloading and installing this certificate manually into the system keychain solves this issue.

Comment: Amazing. That's exactly what happened to me using Github Actions. Just installed the Apple PKI certificates on System keychain and it worked, after 8 hours struggling with this issue. Thanks so much!